# Where is wrong in the derivation about adiabatic theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, adiabatic, berry-pancharatnam-phase

There is a homework in Quantum Mechanics which is about adiabatic theorem. Let us argue where is wrong in following derivation.

$$i \partial_t |\psi(t)\rangle = H(t) |\psi (t)\rangle \tag{1}$$
if $\psi(0)\rangle = |E_0(0)\rangle$, then 
$$|\psi(t)\rangle =\mathcal{T}\exp(-i \int_0^{t}H(t')dt')|\psi(0)\rangle \tag{2}$$
If $H(t)$ changes very slowly and there is always energy gap and no degeneracy no energy level crossing, by [adiabatic theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem)
$$|\psi(t)\rangle= \exp(-i \int_0^tE_0(t')dt')\exp(-\int_0^t\langle E_0|\dot E_0\rangle d t') |E_0(t)\rangle\tag{3}$$

So from above, obviously $|\psi(t)\rangle$ is an instantaneous eigenstate of $H(t)$
$$H(t)|\psi(t)\rangle=E_0(t)|\psi(t)\rangle \tag{4}$$
Substitute $(4)$ into $(1)$, we get
$$i \partial_t |\psi(t)\rangle =E_0(t)|\psi(t)\rangle \tag{5}$$
with $|\psi(0)\rangle=|E_0(0)\rangle$.
The solution of $(5)$ is 
$$|\psi(t)\rangle= \exp(-i \int_0^tE_0(t')dt') |E_0(0)\rangle \tag{6}$$ 
which is not $(3)$. And $(6)$ is even not an instantaneous eigenstate of $H(t)$.  Where is wrong in the above derivation?

Comment: The last formula is not a solution of (5), as seen if you calculate $i\partial_t\exp(-i\int_0^tE_0(t')dt')|E_0(t)\rangle=\exp(-i\int_0^tE_0(t')dt')\{E_0(t)|E_0(t)\rangle+E_0(t)i\partial_t|E_0(t)\rangle\}$. In comparison with the right hand side of (5) there is an extra term. Actually it is the derivative $i\partial_t|E_0(t)\rangle$ where the geometric phase resides.

Comment: @AlexeySokolik Sorry. A little typo. The solution of $(5)$ is $|\psi(t)\rangle= \exp(-i \int_0^tE_0(t')dt') |E_0(t_0)\rangle$

Comment: In this case $|\psi(t)\rangle$ is no longer an instantaneous eigenstate of $H(t)$, so (5) does not follow from (1).

Comment: @AlexeySokolik I know the result is not an eigenstate of $H(t)$, but where is wrong in the derivation? It seems all reasonable.

Comment: The general solution for a time-dependent Hamiltonian is not (2). I don't know what the weird looking $T$ is, but the solution needs to be a series.

Comment: @QuantumBrick $\mathcal{T}$ is the time order operator. The general  solution is  $(2)$. You can expand by Dyson's series. Almost every QM textbook will talk this.

Comment: @QuantumBrick https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_series